# When I click on Downloads, Files (File Manager) totally closes itself

Tags: 13.10, files, downloads

I'm a total newbie to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so please keep it at very basic English please. :)

My problems/issues:
1) Downloads closes itself
2) Javascript?
3) Ubuntu-friendly alternative to SlimCleaner.

1.) This morning I downloaded a video to my Downloads folder using Deluge. Later when I wanted to watch the movie I opened Files, then clicked on Downloads... and Files closed itself straight away.

I once again clicked Files, but instead of clicking on Downloads I clicked on the other folders like Documents and Pictures. They opened fine. But seconds after I clicked and opened Downloads it closes Files completely.

I am totally baffled by this. I opened Files again, right-clicked on Downloads and ran a virus scan with ClamTK on Downloads. There is/was something like 10 files in there, and a virus did pop up, something like .phishing.bank or something. I quarantined it, but the problem still persist.

On Askubuntu I searched everywhere, also Googled for a solution. The nearest page describing my problem is at https://askubuntu.com/questions/249457/nautilus-closes-immediately-when-i-click-on-folder-desktop-empty, but there's no solution there even for an older version than my Ubuntu 13.10.

I tried everything else I could think of. I did restart the computer, I even used the search function to get the video, then moved the video from there to a Windows folder (I'm running Ubuntu next to Windows 7 Ultimate) and then I deleted the movie's folder in Downloads while still in the search bar.

But when opening Files again, then clicking Downloads, it only opens for a few secons allowing me to see what is inside before it closes Files (or File Manager, what is the right name?) again.

I tried clicking 'Downloads' on the left-hand pane (the grey one) as well as the right-hand (white/pink) pane, same story. Updates are up to date. Using Ubuntu 13.10.

Anyone that wants to share my baffle and come of with a brilliant easy to understand solution? :)

Oh, I just remember: Yesterday evening I 'cut' most of the files (not all) in Ubuntu Downloads, and pasted them in Windows Downloads because my space on the Ubuntu side is only 30 Gb. When I checked Downloads 30 minutes ago (for the few seconds before it closed itself again) those files are still showing in Ubuntu Downloads, but all of them 0 kb in size. And when I checked just now, they showed with their original file sizes again!

Yesterday evening I also changed the default grid view that files and folders are shown in, to 'tree view' after I discovered 'File Preferences'. Right now I opened 'files'>Preferences again and changed it back to grid view. But a minute later I opened Preferences again and change it back to list view... but after closing the settings panel it stayed in grid view even though it should've shown files in list view. So I closed Files and re-open it again, just to see it is now in List View again.

Downloads on the Windows-side works fine, it is only Ubuntu's Downloads' folder that are playing ghost-ghost with me.

2.)  Another thing: Ant Video Downloader suddenly stopped working yesterday afternoon, saying something about a Java/javascript error when I tried to download a video that it detected at YouTube. So I installed something about/from Java at Ubuntu Software Center (can't remember the name, and don't know where to look for it, I'm newbie remember, all that I know is it got good stars and reviews there and is not from Oracle), but that did not solve the Ant-problem. Can this be related to the Downloads-problem I'm having?

3.) I was looking for a trouble-shooter program similar to SlimCleaner this morning, but couldn't find one yet. Any suggestions?

I would really appreciate some help, especially with the Downloads-issue.

-Gunther

Comment: could you fire up a terminal (fastest way is to push Ctrl+Alt+T), enter the command `ls -al ~/Downloads`, then add the output of that command to your question? This will allow you to see the contents of the Downloads folder, including hidden files :)

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: Hi Malte. I performed the command, but isn't comfortable pasting the output here because my Downloads folder contain sensitive info, which is shown in Terminal's result. There isn't showing any hidden files in Terminal's output though, only the files I know to be in Downloads. After posting my question (question 2 I thought may have been related to question 1, so I thought it may be helpful to add that, Mateo) I download two other file managers, PCmanFM and Thunar, and Downloads works fine when using them. So it appears as if I'm having my main problem only while using Nautilus. Corrupt file?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem with File Manager closing after trying to open the Downloads directory. What I did was run ClamTK on the Downloads directory. It found 6 threats, all related to files downloaded for one of my Windows systems. I deleted those files and now the Downloads directory opens in File Manager successfully.